# Невидимые входные параметры метода

Tags: c#

Есть метод. В этом методе должны кое-какие данные из основной программы, где этот метод и вызывается. Можно ли как-нибудь прописать входные данные в реализации метода, но так, чтобы эти данные передавались автоматически и я не указывал их каждый раз, при его вызове.
Например :

```
Security sec = new Security();
GetData();
---------------
---------------
--------------
public void GetData(Security sec)
{
int count = sec.Count;
}
```

Верхняя часть и нижняя находятся в разных классах.

Comment: [Необязательные аргументы](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/named-and-optional-arguments)

Comment: Если вопрос в том, чтобы передавать конкретную переменную в метод не указывая это явно - то нет, так нельзя.

Comment: если не хотите передавать значение через параметры - положите его в поле класса

Comment: Сделайте статичный класс `Storage` со статичным полем `Security` а в метод  `GetData(Security sec)` измените на `GetData(Security sec = Storage.Security)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Фактически, вопрос заключается не в невидимых параметрах, а в передаче контекста между методами.

Ты можешь создать явный класс-контекст, проинициализировать его `new Security()` и передавать его во все методы, как обязательный параметр.

Можешь вызывать методы через него, имея доступ к этой "скрытой" переменной.

Можешь создать синглтон, если в один момент времени только один поток управляет этим параметром.

Ну, а можешь сделать ленивую передачу через [`AsyncLocal`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/dn906268(v=vs.110).aspx). Только стоит учитывать, что отсутствие строгих связей затрудняет восприятие кода, а найти зависимости становится значительно сложнее.

```
class Security
{
    private static readonly AsyncLocal<Security> _asyncLocal = new AsyncLocal<Security>();

    public static Security Current
    {
        get => _asyncLocal.Value;
        set => _asyncLocal.Value = value;
    }

    public Int32 Count { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Security.Current = new Security();
        try
        {
            GetData();
            GetData();
            GetData();
        }
        finally
        {
            Security.Current = null;
        }
    }

    public static void GetData()
    {
        int count = Security.Current.Count;
    }
}
```